# Laravel `->whereDate` doesnt include today

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Laravel `->whereDate` doesnt include today.

I have 2 datetime col on my DB (start and end). I use this to query

```
$result = BlaModel::where('status', '=', "bla")
                    ->whereDate('start', '<=', $date)
                    ->whereDate('end', '>', $date)
                    ->get();
```

The `$date` variable is a string `2020-03-25 11:23:09` and I have an entry on my db with

```
start - 2020-03-18 10:44:00
end - 2020-03-25 20:59:00
```

Question: Why does this query does not fetch that entry. Any advice will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because whereDate will change to raw sql with mysql inbuilt-method `DATE()`:

```sql
select *
from `blas`
where date(`start`) <= '2020-03-25 11:23:09'
and date(`end`) > '2020-03-25 11:23:09'
```

So `date(2020-03-25 20:59:00) => 2020-03-25` which is less than '2020-03-25 11:23:09'.

You can change your code to

```php
$result = BlaModel::where('status', '=', "bla")
                    ->where('start', '<=', $date)
                    ->where('end', '>', $date)
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

**If you want use `WhereDate` write your query like.**

```
$result = BlaModel::where('status', '=', "bla")
                    ->whereDate('start', '<=', \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-03-18 10:44:00')->format('Y-m-d'))
                    ->whereDate('end', '>',\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-03-25 20:59:00')->format('Y-m-d'))
                    ->get();
```

**Or use Simple `Where` like**

```
$result = BlaModel::where('status', '=', "bla")
                    ->where('start', '<=', $date)
                    ->where('end', '>', $date)
                    ->get();
```